# Partial derivative of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

### Question

I have the following ordinary differential equation (ODE)

$\frac{du(s)}{ds}=f(s) + u(s)$

which can be written in my case as

$\frac{d}{ds}u[x(s),y(s)]=f[x(s),y(s)] + u[x(s),y(s)]$.

How do I find $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$?

### What I tried

I take the partial derivative on both sides and I exchange the order of derivatives

$\frac{d}{ds}\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}u[x(s),y(s)]\right\}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left\{f[x(s),y(s)] + u[x(s),y(s)]\right\}$

now, I define

$g(s)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$

which implies I can find $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ by solving the following ODE for $g(s)$

$\frac{dg(s)}{ds}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f[x(s),y(s)] + g(s)$

Could someone confirm whether this is correct?

### Counter-Example

Here is an example where my above statement is wrong. I define

$x(s)=\cos(s)\\ 
y(s)=s^2\\
u(x,y)=2x+y^2\\
f(x,y)=4y^{3/2}-y^2-2x-\sqrt{1-x^2}$

one can verify with some algebra that it satisfies (by design)

$\frac{du(s)}{ds}=f(s) + u(s)$

in fact, both sides are equal

$\frac{du(s)}{ds}=4s^3-2\sin(s)=f(s) + u(s)$

However

$\frac{d}{ds}\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}u[x(s),y(s)]\right\}=4s$

while

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left\{f[x(s),y(s)] + u[x(s),y(s)]\right\}=6s$

So my original question remains: given an ODE for $u(s)$ what ODE defines $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$?

### Solution

Based on feedback from @lord-commander, I realized that my proposed approach was completely wrong. In fact, the unknown partial derivative $\partial u/\partial y$ that I am looking for is related to the given functions by the following partial differential equation, not by an ODE.

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}=f(s)+u(s)$

It seems to me then that my only option is to solve the original linear ODE

$\frac{du(s)}{ds}=f(s) + u(s)$

which has a general solution

$u(s) = c_1 e^s + e^s \int_1^s f(s') e^{-s'} ds'$

Then I write this as a function of $(x,y)$ and take the partial derivative.

This is the approach I was trying to avoid. In fact, my expression is complicated and the integral has to be done numerically, for many values of $s$ with $f(s)$ a computationally expensive function.

Comment: Why do you want to introduce $g(s)$. Couldn't you just solve this as a Linear First Order ODE?

Comment: The ODE for $u(s)$ is in principle solvable by standard means indeed. But in my real-world problem, it leads to a very complicated expression without an analytic solution. I have to find both $u(s)$ and $\partial u/\partial y$ using a numerical ODE integrator. I just need to write down the right ODE.

Comment: i see, i was thinking of your post and if you want to solve this problem parametrically then i don't think there is a nicer form than i described.    

Unless if this is a textbook problem, in which case it might have a nice solution.    

But hey you are in luck, if you have a spefic problem all you need to do is solve the problem as you have predicted it. Then plug in your solution into the original ODE.

Comment: Also, do you mean you can't integrate it?

Comment: I need to know $u(s)$ at many values of $s$. And $f(s)$ takes quite some time to compute. It would be too computationally expensive to integrate $u(s)$ at every $s$. An ODE would seem more efficient. If I knew how to write it down for $\partial u/\partial y$. Youre answer does not quite answer my question yet.

Comment: Nice, so you have disproven your claim. Which means it is wrong. You cannot introduce $g(s)$ because your way of multiplying out $\frac{d}{d s}$ is illegal.

Comment: Indeed, my statement is wrong and thus I am still looking for the right ODE to compute $\partial u/\partial y$

Comment: Maybe you could expand on the relation between $x$ and $y$. This kind of question feels like asking "what's $\int\int \xi(f(x),f(y))dxdy$?"

Answer (score 1):

I have the following differential equation

$$\frac{du(t)}{dt}=f(t) + u(t)$$

> I decided to use $t$ because my eyes just didn't work with $s$, but feel free to read the last equation and change the $t$-s back to $s$.

which can be written in my case as

$$\frac{d}{dt}u(x,y)=f(x,y)+ u(x,y)$$

Both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ depend parametrically on $t$.

$$u(x(t),y(t))=u(x,y)$$

By the chain rule:

$$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}u(x,y)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$

$d$ is the total derivative, $\partial$ is a partial derivative.

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=f(x,y)+u(x,y)$$

$$\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\right)=\frac{d}{dy}\left(f(x,y)+u(x,y)\right)$$

$$\frac{d\;\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}}{d y}+\frac{d\;\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}}{dy}=\frac{d}{dy}\left(f(x,y)+u(x,y)\right)$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)\cdot \frac{\partial t}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\right)\cdot\frac{\partial{t}}{\partial y}=\frac{d}{dy}\left(f(x,y)+u(x,y)\right)$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)\cdot \frac{\partial t}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\right)\cdot\frac{\partial{t}}{\partial y}=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\underbrace{\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}}_{1}\right)$$

To be completely frank i am not really sure if you can multiply out by $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}$ as the functions they are differentiating are different. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question. I would appreciate it if you could elaborate on your answer to show why you are correct.